# Use of event.stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the case of a game where user have to click/use keys mutli and many times,

> Is there any advantage to use event.stopPropagation() in all event
>   handler which i know bubbling is useless?

Suppose i have a div with a click event binded,

```
<div id="mydiv">CLICK</div>
$('#mydiv').click(function(){...});
```

if i click on it, this event will propagate to all ancestors elements of this div (e.g body/html/document/window). So just wondering if this could be better or same or worst to stop immediatly propagation of event.

In fact, i don't know how javascript engine internally deal with events binded (or not) to elements, if this works as a listener or what...

Comment: I can't think of a reason to stop the propagation unless you specifically didn't want the event to be handled by an ancestor element that binds to it.

Comment: @KevinB so javascript doesn't follow all hierachy of ancestors to 'check' if a specific event is binded? Its just do nothing?

Comment: The event does still bubble up the tree, but why would you stop it? It's more processor intensive to bind to every element and stop propagation than it would be to just let it continue.

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to know what the difference between `stopPropagation` and `stopImmediatePropagation` is?

Comment: Events happen whether you bind to them or not. For example, a span element that comes after that div also responds to clicks. When you click on it, a click event happens that then bubbles up the DOM hierarchy. Your code is simply listening for the event.

Comment: @KevinB "It's more processor intensive to bind to every element and stop propagation" I don't want to bind all ancestors elements, i just wondering if stopping propagation of an event to not bubble to its ancestors can be of any advantage or not

Comment: It is only an advantage if you specifically didn't want ancestors to be able to respond to the event. (Which is just another way of putting my first comment.)

Comment: Ok thx Kevin for your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit general, but to answer your direct question, unless you need to stop propagation then there is no reason to do so. Propagation is not what is going to hinder the efficiency of your game, it's having too many event bindings. Consider using a generic binding on a parent element and then processing the actual target of the event to determine what action to take.

Comment: "unless you need to stop propagation then there is no reason to do so" thx i'll take it as answer